# do while trouble with try catch enclosed

Tags: java

I am trying to get my do while block to run correctly. Enclosed within is a try and catch block which is only partially working. I would like it to catch an exception (`InputMismatchException`) when something other than an Int is entered and also catch an exception when dividing by zero. If either of the catches occur then the purpose is that it goes back to the try again by means of the do while loop. Currently, it is working for the `ArithmeticException` but not for the `InputMismatchException`. When I type in characters instead of an Int it appears to loop nonstop. Please help. I don't understand why the one works and not the other.

```
    int div;
    boolean check = true;

    while (check) {
        boolean result = true;
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("The following operation will divide the first number by the second.");
                System.out.println("Enter first number.");
                example.a = user_input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter second number.");
                example.b = user_input.nextInt();

                div = example.div();
                System.out.println("The result of this division is " + div);
                result = true;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("That is not a number. Please try again.");
                result = false;
            } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
                System.out.println("Division by zero.");
                result = false;
            }
        } while (result = true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting an `InputMismatchException` will not skip past the bad data, so the next call to `nextInt()` will fail with the same reason. You should try calling `nextLine()` in your catch:

```
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("That is not a number. Please try again.");
    result = false;
    user_input.nextLine(); // Advance past the bad stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
while (result = true)
```

should be

```
while (result == true)
```

or just

```
while (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove your do, just use a while loop

and change your second while to

```
while(result)
```